# TYPO3 SQL error: Field 'tx_imagezoom_set' doesn't have a default value

Tags: sql, typo3

I need to add content onto an existing page on a TYPO3 website (version 9.5.22) and whenever I click on "save" following error occurs:

> SQL error: 'Field 'tx_imagezoom_set' doesn't have a default value' (tt_content:NEW64187cc972b4d840487066)

Since there is no field called `tx_imagezoom_set` I can't define that value via TYPO3. I am thankful for any help and look forward for any suggestion since I don't have the option to access the ftp files e.g. to code anything.

Comment: One of your extension does need that field and it's not properly configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have a database with strict mode activated. The ugly solution would be to disable the strict mode in the database configuration.

But better search the extensions in `typo3conf/ext`. Each extension that provides new database fields has a file called `ext_tables.sql`. There you need to set the default value.

Update:
I just read your question again. Without file access there is no way to fix this error!

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @peter-kraume answer:
It is also possible to assign a default value to the field from the TCA. This also applies if the field is not visibly editable in the current record.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/Default.html#tca-property-default

Of course, only if you have file access.